# SageMaker get feature store values with HTTP request

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-sagemaker

I created a feature group and ingested data to it using the Python SDK of Amazon SageMaker.  Now, to get the values of the features I could use the "get_record" API of Python, as shown below:

```
customer_id = 'xyz
sample_record = sagemaker_session.boto_session.client('sagemaker-featurestore-runtime', region_name=region).get_record(
    FeatureGroupName=client_behaviour_feature_group_name, RecordIdentifierValueAsString=str(customer_id))
```

It turns out that I wouldn't like to use Python SDK in my production environment, once it's not prepared for that. That's why, I want to know if it's possible to get the records of my feature group in SageMaker using an HTTP request, like if I had an API to consume the production features of my feature store!

I know that a possible option is to use a Lambda function to deploy the Python SDK and consume the features using that Lambda, but using a simple get request from an endpoint seems to be easier.

Answer (score 0):

AWS is a service-oriented architechture, meaning everything (Console, CLI, SDKs) talk to AWS API HTTP endpoints

You can use the CLI:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker-featurestore-runtime/get-record.html

Or the Boto3 SDK:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-featurestore-runtime.html#SageMakerFeatureStoreRuntime.Client.get_record

or the AWS API:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_feature_store_GetRecord.html

Comment: The AWS API seems very similar to an HTTP request: ```GET /FeatureGroup/FeatureGroupName?FeatureName=FeatureNames&RecordIdentifierValueAsString=RecordIdentifierValueAsString```
But, how can I put this in a postman, for example, to test the request of the feature group?